# BT Headset Great on XP, battery dies fast on W7

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, headset

I have a Jabra VBT185Z BT mobile phone headset. I use it on Windows XP with a VoIP softphone. It works very well. Surprisingly the audio quality is great (unlike when used with my phone). I decided to move my VoIP softphone off the XP system and on to a Win7/64 system I have. Naturally I wanted to move the BT headset as well.

All went well, and I was able to pair up and use the headset on Windows 7. **However**... a little while after making my first call, the headset's battery died. Closer inspection revealed:

When running on XP, after making a call, the headset would be released and go into its "standby" mode (no flashing light, etc.), and in that state, the battery would last for days. However, on Windows 7, it appears that the BT system does *not* release the headset, instead leaving it active "permanently". In this state, slow flashing light, it dies in a couple of hours or less.

This is the same VoIP softphone (CounterPath Bria 3), same Targus ACB10US Bluetooth adapter. However the bluetooth driver package looks different. This is the venerable Targus, or is it Broadcom, or is it WIDCOMM (???) driver package, but I think the one for Windows 7 is newer. At least it looks different operationally.

I know this is a long winded question: **How can I make it so that Windows 7 releases my BT headset?** I'm asking because I had a similar problem with USB drives not being put into standby by Win7 when dismounted (and they were on XP), and I finally found a registry hack that changed Windows 7's behavior to put the USB drives into standby after dismount. I'm hoping there is something like that for a BT headset.

Comment: very tiny relation to your problem . http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows/Bluetooth-mic-delay-after-call-initiation/td-p/328196  .  makes me wonder if some mic listening component via the windows sound recording controls exists? it was hard to find anything on the web.

Comment: Thanks, it was interesting. Oddly I have the opposite problem. I can't stop it from being hot all the time and killing the headset battery on the W7 system.